# Cannot overwrite file /home/baadshah/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/toolchains.xml: Permission denied

Tags: application-development

```
Cannot overwrite file /home/baadshah/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/qtversion.xml: 
Permission denied
Cannot overwrite file /home/baadshah/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/toolchains.xml: 
Permission denied
Cannot overwrite file /home/baadshah/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/devices.xml:
Permission denied
Cannot overwrite file /home/baadshah/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/toolchains.xml: 
Permission denied
```

I am getting these 4 errors when opening Qt and uinable to find application when opening a new files

Answer (score 9):

Qt installer adds the configuration directories with root as the owner.

You need to own the files and directories to a file to be able to write into a file. So set permissions like this on each of the files:

```
sudo -s chmod o+w /home/baadshah/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/*.xml
```

If the directories

```
/home/baadshah/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/
/home/baadshah/.config/QtProject/
```

are owned by someone else than your username (ie. `root`) you need to change that too. If so you can change this with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/baadshah/.config/QtProject/
```